# After Update Panel code, some calculations value cannot set into textbox.

Tags: c#, asp.net

In this code, this text change method is called from update panel trigger here, I perform some calculation (i.e. sum the gridview cell value) and store calculation result at total variable. Then assign this total variable to txtTotalAmount textbox, but this value is not visible into this textbox after successfull execution of code.

For Help thanks in advance:

```
protected void txtProductPrice_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs)
        {
            DataTable dt;
            DataRow dr = null;
            if (ViewState["CurrentData"] != null)
            {
                dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentData"];
                dr = dt.NewRow();

                dr[0] = ddlProductName.SelectedItem.Value;
                dr[1] = ddlProductName.SelectedItem.ToString();
                dr[2] = txtQuantity.Text;
                dr[3] = txtUnit.Text;
                dr[4] = txtProductPrice.Text;
                dr[5] = Convert.ToDouble(txtProductPrice.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(txtQuantity.Text);

                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            else
            {
                dt = new DataTable();

                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("prcode", typeof(string)));//for TextBox value   
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("prname", typeof(string)));//for TextBox value   
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("qty", typeof(string)));//for TextBox value   
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("unit", typeof(string)));//for TextBox value   
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("price", typeof(string)));//for TextBox value   
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("total", typeof(string)));//for TextBox value   

                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr[0] = ddlProductName.SelectedItem.Value;
                dr[1] = ddlProductName.SelectedItem.ToString();
                dr[2] = txtQuantity.Text;
                dr[3] = txtUnit.Text;
                dr[4] = txtProductPrice.Text;
                dr[5] = Convert.ToDouble(txtProductPrice.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(txtQuantity.Text);

                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            grdSaleInvoice.DataSource = dt;
            grdSaleInvoice.DataBind();

            ViewState["CurrentData"] = dt;
            double total = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < grdSaleInvoice.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                total += Convert.ToDouble(((TextBox)grdSaleInvoice.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("total")).Text);
            }
            txtTotalAmount.Text = total.ToString();
        }
```

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableEventValidation="true" CodeBehind="SaleInvoice.aspx.cs" Inherits="POS.SaleInvoice" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div id="content-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">           
            <form runat="server">
                <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label>Invoice No</label>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ReadOnly="true" CssClass="form-control" ID="txtInvoiceNo" placeholder="Auto"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label>Invoice Type</label>
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ID="ddlInvoiceType" placeholder="Invoice Type">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Invoice Type" Value="-1">Invoice Type</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Credit" Value="1">Credit</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Cash" Value="2">Cash</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label>Customer</label>
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ID="ddlCustomer" placeholder="Customer"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <label>Invoice Date</label>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ID="dtInvoiceDate"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                        <label>Remarks</label>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ID="txtRemarks" placeholder="Remarks"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row" id="productData">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label>Pr. Code</label>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control" EnableViewState="true" value="" AutoPostBack="true" ID="txtProductCode" placeholder="Code" OnTextChanged="txtProductCode_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label>Pr. Name</label>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="form-control" value="" ID="ddlProductName" placeholder="Name" DataTextField="product_name" DataValueField="product_id"></asp:DropDownList>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                            <Triggers>
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtProductCode" EventName="TextChanged" />
                            </Triggers>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label>Quantity</label>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control" value="" ID="txtQuantity" placeholder="Quantity"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label>Unit</label>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ReadOnly="true" value="" ID="txtUnit" Text="Piece"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label>Price</label>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control" value="" ID="txtProductPrice" AutoPostBack="true" placeholder="Price" OnTextChanged="txtProductPrice_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label>Total</label>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ReadOnly="true" CssClass="form-control" value="" ID="txtTotal" placeholder="Total"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdSaleInvoice" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" GridLines="Horizontal" ForeColor="Black" Width="100%">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Pr. Code">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="prcode" Text='<%# Bind("prcode") %>' ReadOnly="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Pr. Name">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="prname" Text='<%# Bind("prname") %>' ReadOnly="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="qty" Text='<%# Bind("qty") %>' ReadOnly="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unit">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="unit" Text='<%# Bind("unit") %>' ReadOnly="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="price" Text='<%# Bind("price") %>' ReadOnly="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="total" Text='<%# Bind("total") %>' ReadOnly="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                                    <ItemTemplate>                                        
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:30px">delete</i></asp:LinkButton>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" />
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
                            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4B4B4B" />
                            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
                            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#242121" />
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtProductPrice" EventName="TextChanged" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Discount</label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDiscount"  CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Discount" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Tax</label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtTax"  CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Tax" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Total Amount</label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalAmount" EnableViewState="true"  CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Total Amount" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>`enter code here`
                <br />
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success btn-group-lg" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
                        <a href="ProductList.aspx" id="btnCancle" runat="server" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Your update occurs inside the update panel, how does the label OUTSIDE the update panel gets update without a postback?

Comment: any solution of this problem....

Comment: Move your script manager to Global. Then wrap your content wrapper with update panel. It should recognize where the update is taking place. Also, check if there are codes running in page load that will potentially change any values you are trying pass.

Comment: another issue, when I press delete button it will delete row but it refresh page. i want to delete row using partial page refresh. `<asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:30px">delete</i></asp:LinkButton>`

Comment: LinkButton linkButton = (LinkButton)sender;
 GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)linkButton.NamingContainer;
int rowID = gvRow.RowIndex;
if (ViewState["CurrentData"] != null)
{
DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentData"];
if (dt.Rows.Count >= 1)
{if (gvRow.RowIndex < dt.Rows.Count){dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows[rowID]);                     }}
ViewState["CurrentData"] = dt;
grdSaleInvoice.DataSource = dt;
grdSaleInvoice.DataBind();
} }

Comment: You are calling the wrong event. You should be using Gridview events for any interactions inside the gridview. See sample in here,  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/all-gridview-events-for-beginners1